# how to listen to the layer control events of a react-leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm following this example

[image]

https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-layers-control

to build in a small ionic+react app.

How could I listen to change of state of each of the overlay layers checkboxes?

I would like to change the center and zoom of my map to show all makers of the active overlay layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tap into the `eventHandlers` prop of each layer, which is just a wrapper for all the event handlers that can be added to any leaflet layer.  So you can tap into the `add` and `remove` events, and listen for those events on each layer.  Those events are triggered when adding and removing layers with the LayersControl:

```js
    <MapContainer {...props}>
      <LayersControl collapsed={false}>
        <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="OpenStreetMap.Mapnik">
          <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            eventHandlers={{
              add: (e) => {
                console.log("Added Layer:", e.target);
              },
              remove: (e) => {
                console.log("Removed layer:", e.target);
              }
            }}
          />
        </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
        <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite">
          <TileLayer
            url="https://tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            eventHandlers={{
              add: (e) => {
                console.log("Added Layer:", e.target);
              },
              remove: (e) => {
                console.log("Removed layer:", e.target);
              }
            }}
          />
        </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
        <LayersControl.Overlay name="Marker with popup">
          <Marker
            position={center}
            eventHandlers={{
              add: (e) => {
                console.log("Added Layer:", e.target);
              },
              remove: (e) => {
                console.log("Removed layer:", e.target);
              }
            }}
          >
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </LayersControl.Overlay>
      </LayersControl>
    </MapContainer>
```

### [Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-hermann-q0k8e)